# Python 3.7 + tkInter : How can I make sure a button is assigned an individual function from a file?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am having some issues wrapping my head around something I encountered in python recently.

So, basically, I want to allow for a user to load several json files, all listed in a python list. These files contain parameters used to create buttons with, namely, the color the button should have, the text that should be displayed in it and the command that it needs to execute once clicked.

```
        def createTags(self):
        for items in self.LoadedInstallProfiles:
            with open(items, "r") as jsonfiles:
                self.loadeddata = json.load(jsonfiles)
                self.tag = Button(self.tagmenu, text=self.loadeddata.get("profilename"), background=
                self.loadeddata.get("profilecolor"), command=print(self.loadeddata.get("profilename")))
                self.tag.pack(side="top",fill="x")
```

The problem is: the buttons show up with their individual color and text, but all seem to print out the same profilename when clicked, which is that in the last json file in the list.

Comment: Try this. `command=lambda x=self.loadeddata.get("profilename": print(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

I common way is to store the created button widgets in a list. I have modified your method. See below.

```
def createTags(self):

    # First create the widget and append to list variable 
    self.tags = [] #List to store button widgets
    for items in self.LoadedInstallProfiles:
        with open(items, "r") as jsonfiles:
            loadeddata = json.load(jsonfiles)
            text = loadeddata.get("profilename")
            bg = loadeddata.get("profilecolor")
            tag = Button( self.tagmenu, text=text, background=bg, command=print(text) )
            self.tag.append( tag )

    # Then display the widgets
    for tag in self.tags:
        tag.pack(side="top",fill="x")
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the problem with `command=print(self.loadeddata.get("profilename"))` is similar to the problem with lambda statements (that said I am surprised your buttons work at all They should print once at `init` and then never work after that because you are calling print at button creation instead of saving a reference to print).

Due to the nature of how lambda works here in a loop like this you end up only printing the last value in the loop for all commands. Instead you need to use a lambda statement and also define the value in the lambda for each loop to accurately record the correct data for the print statement.\

I created 3 test files for this:

`test.json`:

```
{"profilename":"test", "profilecolor": "green"}
```

`test2.json`:

```
{"profilename":"test2", "profilecolor": "blue"}
```

`test3.json`:

```
{"profilename":"test3", "profilecolor": "orange"}
```

Example code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import json

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn_list = []
        for file in ['test.json', 'test2.json', 'test3.json']:
            with open(file, 'r') as f:
                self.btn_list.append(json.load(f))

        self.create_tags()

    def create_tags(self):
        for item in self.btn_list:
            tk.Button(self, text=item.get("profilename"), background=item.get("profilecolor"),
                      command=lambda x=item.get("profilename"): print(x)).pack(side="top", fill="x")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window().mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]